# A certain type of points in the plane

Tags: geometry, analysis

In the plane a point $O$ and a sequence of points $ P_1 , P_2 , P_3 , ... $ are given. The distances $ OP_1 , OP_2 , OP_3 , ...$  are  $ r_1 , r_2 , r_3 , ....$ , where $ r_1 ≤ r_2 ≤  r_3 ≤  $  ... . Let $ α$ satisfy $ 0 < α < 1$ . Suppose that for every $n$  the distance from the point $P_n$ to another point of the sequence is greater than or equal to $r_n ^α $ . Then does there exist an exponent $β$ , such that for some $C$ independent of $n$ ,

$ r_n $ ≥ $ C$ $ n^β $ , for all $n$ = $ 1 , 2 , $ ...

?

Comment: I don't know. Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @ Gerry: This was one of the longlisted problems of IMO 1967 , I found it in a problem book , where it is said to be non-elementary and not even any hint to the solution is given .